# Allow access to protected file through PHP

Tags: php, curl, header, tar, gzip

I have a set of tar.gz files inside a folder protected against http access via .htaccess.  I wish to allow direct curl downloading of these files via http.  I have done this to things like images by setting the header information to something like:

```
$file='/some/file/protected/by/htaccess.png';
header("Content-type: image/png");
readfile($file);
```

My question:
Is there a way to provide direct access to these tar.gz files in a similar manner to the way I did it with images?

The reason I would like to do it in this way is that I would like to control access to which users can access these files by our site's login system.

Edit: as pointed out by Machavity, my code was pointing at a jpg, and had a png header.

Comment: Why not do a whitelist of the users IPs that can access this directory? Or implement it in php?

Comment: You're calling a `.jpg` file but sending headers for a `.png`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `tar.gz`

```
$filename = 'path/to/your/file.tar.gz';
header('Content-Type: application/x-compressed');
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache");
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . basename($filename) . '"');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($filename));
readfile($filename);
```

Comment: Looks like it works.  Just to clarify, visiting the url containing the code above will simulate visiting the actual tar.gz file itself in a browser, had it not been protected by .htaccess.  Is that correct?